# Dual boot issues win8/ubuntu16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Problem in booting into windows after installing ubuntu

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Selecting Windows 8 from grub menu generates an error message? Windows 8 doesn't appear on the grub menu? Grub menu doesn't appear and system boots straight to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific 
1:if you lost grub use grub recovery commands
2:if the problem is you stuck on purple window then install boot repair and follow instructions

Comment: Sorry for delay i couldn't install windows 8 in my pc. when i boot using live usb i can't select a drive to install windows